# synchronized( obj ) block in java when obj can be null

Tags: java, synchronized

- I have a java `synchronized( obj ) { ... }` block which works fine.
- I want to extend its behavior so that whenever `synchronized( obj == null )` is called, the entire block is skipped.
- Currently I get a null pointer exception.
- Is there any way to achieve this with `synchronized( ... ) { ... }` block?

Comment: you can create an abstract wrapper over this class and with **template design pattern** you can extend this behavior. Idea is to make this future proof also.

Comment: There is no *simple* way to achieve this directly through the sync block. You either do some `if` magic before the block or you delegate this whole thing to a dedcated class. In all cases, the actual lock monitor should never be `null`.

Comment: The design sounds flawed. There is a good reason why a lock/monitor should be `final` and never `null`. Being able to change the lock freely will run you into a lot of trouble.

Comment: It seems that if you are trying to synchronize on something that could potentially become `null`, you are not synchronizing on the right thing. Remember that you synchronize on an object, not a variable. This means that, even after synchronizing, your variable could still become `null`. You should probably have a separate (`final`) variable for your lock.

Comment: So many questions. This appears to be a XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *simple* way to achieve this directly through the sync block.

You either do some `if` magic before the block or you delegate this whole thing to a dedcated class or method. In all cases, the actual lock monitor must never be `null`.

An example, instead of having the actual monitor being `null`, you move this logic one below and wrap the class.

```
public class NullableMonitor {
    private Object monitor;

    // constructor

    public boolean isPresent() {
        return monitor != null;
    }

    // dont forget the synchronized
    public synchronized void setMonitor(Object monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }
}
```

And then in your sync block you use this as monitor.

```
final NullableMonitor monitor = new NullableMonitor(myObject);
...
synchronized (monitor) {
    if (monitor.isPresent()) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

It is critical though that the setter in `NullableMonitor` is synchronized on itself, otherwise someone can mess with the `monitor` between entering and the if-check.

This has as consequence though that you can not call it from within your sync block.

---

Note that your overall concept seems to be flawed and appears very dangerous. There is a reason why people are saying that a monitor/lock for a sync must never be `null` and should always be `final`. The monitor should not be changed, you can easily mess up your logic and run into different issues by that.

Comment: To be honest, I dont think that this answer addresses the actual issue at all. I was thinking a bit about the topic and I wasnt able to come up with any good solution that still has the possibility to have the actual object re-assignable. This answer bypasses the problem by introducing a basically final wrapper. Locking is not happening on the original object anymore, thus it may not even be applicable to the specific situation at all...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void doStuff(Object lock) {
    if (lock == null) return;
    synchronized(lock) {
        // doStuff
    }
}
```

I think the easiest way is to define a private method handling this logic. Furthermore one could replace the task to execute with a functional interface and pass the behavoir as a parameter for multiple usage.

```
interface Wrapper<R,T> {
    public abstract R execute(List<T> args) throws Exception;
}

Wrapper<String, String> wrapper = new Wrapper() {
    @Override
    public String execute(List<String> input) {
        // business code
    }
}

private <R,T> R doStuff(Object lock, Wrapper<R,T> w) throws Exception {
    if (lock == null) return null;
    synchronized(lock) {
        return w.execute();
    }
}
```

If you do not rely on a dedicated lock object, you can also use:

```
synchronized(this){..} // this refers to instance of this class
synchronized(MyClass.class){..} // for static usecase
```

Comment: but this is not atomic ... so the `lock` will pass the if statement, just to face the exact same problem when it reaches the synchronized block ...

Comment: adding `Objects.requireNonNull(instance)` will throw the exception and then you can catch  it and can execute it accordingly

Comment: @OrenIshShalom you mean the if statement is passed and then lock object is set to null by another thread?

Comment: Yes, another thread changes `obj` to null after the if statement passed.

Comment: Tbh why should your code behave like this? Passing an special object to the syncblock must be for some reason, so its basically your responsibility to make it not null.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing is that the object reference may change between the null check and the synchronization. So I would suggest the following:

```java
    var freezeObj = obj; // assuming obj is volatile
    if (freezeObj != null) {
      synchronized (freezeObj) {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

Comment: Since `obj` is not `final` by OPs design, this is also unsafe against modifications from an offending thread.

Comment: That depends on what the synchronization is supposed to achieve. If it is used to defend the `obj` instance the thread sees when entering the synchronization block, it should be okay. But it will not defend against other threads seeing different values of obj itself. For that, you would need an external (ideally final) lock object.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use Lock class from java instead of Object class..

```
  public void doStuff(Lock lock){
      lock.lock();
      //doStuff
      lock.unlock();
  }
```